# how can i fix this issue : ContextErrorException in StandardServiceContainer.php line 276: Notice: Undefined index: thelia

Tags: symfony, indexing, e-commerce, undefined

I want to try thelia ecommerce symfony2 solution on my localhost wamp but I am getting this error :

> ContextErrorException in StandardServiceContainer.php line 276: Notice:
>   Undefined index: thelia
>   in StandardServiceContainer.php line 276
>   at ErrorHandler->handleError('8', 'Undefined index: thelia', 'C:\wamp\www\thelia\core\vendor\propel\propel\src\Propel\Runtime\ServiceContainer\StandardServiceContainer.php',
>   '276', array('name' => 'thelia')) in StandardServiceContainer.php line
>   276
>       at StandardServiceContainer->getConnectionManager('thelia') in StandardServiceContainer.php line 356
>       at StandardServiceContainer->getReadConnection('thelia') in ModelCriteria.php line 970
>       at ModelCriteria->find() in ModuleQuery.php line 32
>       at ModuleQuery::getActivated() in Thelia.php line 226
>       at Thelia->loadConfiguration(object(TheliaContainerBuilder)) in Thelia.php line 427
>       at Thelia->buildContainer() in Kernel.php line 533
>       at Kernel->initializeContainer() in Kernel.php line 130
>       at Kernel->boot() in Thelia.php line 147
>       at Thelia->boot() in Kernel.php line 185
>       at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index_dev.php line 36

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a file C:\wamp\www\thelia\local\config\database.yml ?

If this is not the case, run the command

```
composer run-script post-create-project-cmd
```

Comment: First tnx for replying MrGuillou , in C:\wamp\www\thelia\local\config\  i have database.yml.sample is it the same ?

Comment: Now it gives me Script "post-create-project-cmd" is not defined in this package in line command , i'm sorry but i'm new in symfony2 .